# Content of span tag gets chopped off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have names displayed vertically. Basically this is the structure of my html page.

```
<div>                                  <div/>
  <a>name<span>Details</span></a>          <a>name<span>Details</span></a>      
  <a>name<span>Details</span></a>         <a>name<span>Details</span></a>
</div>                                 </div>
```

So each "a" tag contains a name and span tag contains details about that name. The display attribute of the span tag is set to "none" to start and is changed to "block" when mouse is hovered over "a" tag content. The problem is the span tag content gets chopped off in IE8. Works fine in Firefox and chrome.

My CSS file:

```
#tooltip1 { position: relative; }
#tooltip1 a{text-decoration: none; color:#000000;} 
#tooltip1 a span { display: none; color: #FFFFFF; }    
#tooltip1 a:hover span { display: block; position: absolute; 
                         background-color: #aaa; color: #FFFFFF; 
                         padding: 5px; height: 10px; 
                         width:500px; }
```

I have my mouse over "OMA" in this picture, and instead of showing "OMAHA NEBRASKA", it only shows "OMAHA" What can I do for IE to show all the text? I have tried working with the "overflow" attribute but it didn't work.

[image: Picture of what it looks like in my system]

This is the link to jsfiddle which has all the codes if want to take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/7s4Np/10/

Comment: Check this fork with simpler HTML structure to see what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/dBqeC/ — works ok in my IE9 with IE8 mode.

Comment: It works in jsfiddle but not when I run my application. In jsfiddle, it works even without the z-index attribute.

Comment: If it only fails in your application, then we'd need to see **your application** to help with the problem.

Comment: @KatieK unfortunately only the employees have access to the application. The application runs on IE8. Any kind of tip would be greatly appreciated. Thank you Katie

Comment: `<span>` vs `<span/>` ? I notice on a couple of the tags above you have `<span/>` as your opening tag. Which I don't think is correct, also depending on which DOC TYPE your using that may be treating it as a closing tag of sorts, when its not. (same thing for the divs you use)

Comment: @chris Thank you.. Those are just typos. I have fixed them. I just wanted people to see what the basic structure of my page was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the css of the class .container which was applied to the div tag. Although my question here doesn't show the div applying .container class, it shows that in the jsfiddle link that I posted.

This is where the problem lied:

```
.container {width: 100px; float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 10px;}
```

I deleted the "overflow: hidden" attribute and it worked like a charm.

In my previous attempt to solve this, I had applied "overflow: visible" to the child element(span tag). Isn't the value(overflow: visible) in the child element supposed to over the value(overflow: hidden) defined in the parent element?

Anyway thank you all you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying z-index to  a:hover span

```
#tooltip1 a:hover span{ z-index:5; }
```

I think a tooltip is being hidden behind the next relative element in the flow, and spans with non-transparent background-color in it.